# How to call a method from another c# script using invoke?

Tags: c#, unity

I want to call a method from another script in my script using Invoke(),but unable to run it.How can i achieve this ?

Following is my code -

```
void Start () {

    int randNum;
    randNum = Random.Range(0,2);

    Debug.Log("random number == " + randNum);

    if(randNum == 0)
        Invoke("PositionScript.instance.MAttack",5f);

    if(randNum == 1)
        Invoke("PositionScript.instance.SAttack",5f);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in [Invoke](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) takes only the name of the method you wish to call.

Assuming `PositionScript.instance` is set to a MonoBehaviour component of some sort:

```
PositionScript.instance.Invoke("MAttack",5f);
```