# Calling Functions from Other Scripts

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

Say I have three different `gameObjevcts`, each representing rock, paper or scissors. These objects all have a `Player` script attached to them. The `Player` script has two functions i want to use, `MoveSelected()`, `MoveNotSeleccted()`. When the function `CPUMove()` is called, I want the program to randomly choose one of the three moves. My question is, how do I call a either of the functions fro another script `RPS_Game`? I thought of using Invoke() somehow but after trying couple of things with it, I got no where. Can someone please help me out?

```
public class RPS_Game {
    public void CPUMove() {
        int rand = Random.Range(1, 3);

        if(rand == 1) {
          //call MoveSelected() for one of the three Player objects and 
            MoveNotSelected() for the other two
        }
        else if(rand == 2) {
          //call MoveSelected() for one of the three Player objects and 
            MoveNotSelected() for the other two
        }
        else if(rand == 3) {
          //call MoveSelected() for one of the three Player objects and 
            MoveNotSelected() for the other two
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method from another c# script using invoke?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/92893/how-to-call-a-method-from-another-c-script-using-invoke)

Comment: I don't think this question duplicates that one, @SeyedMortezaKamaly. The linked question is specific to using the `Invoke()` method, which isn't mentioned here. One could certainly answer this one using `Invoke()`, but I don't think that would be the best answer to direct users to in this case.

Comment: Ahmed, post your Player script, and a screenshot of your object hierarchy as well. These kinds of questions largely depend on the hierarchy of your objects in your project to determine how to make the calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can just store a public reference to each of the scripts you want, and wire them up in the inspector:

```
public Player rockMove;
public Player paperMove;
public Player scissorsMove;
```

Then your script can say

```
rockMove.MoveSelected();
paperMove.MoveNotSelected();
scissorsMove.MoveNotSelected();
```

Though how I'd do it would be more like this:

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour {

     public enum MoveType : int {
         Rock,
         Paper,
         Scissors
     }

     // This gives us a dropdown in the inspector 
     // to select a move type on each object.
     public MoveType moveType;

     // No need for two methods for on and off,
     // just pass a boolean representing true = selected
     // false = unselected (similar to Unity's SetActive method)
     public void SetMoveSelected(bool selected) {
        // ...
     }
}
```

Then your script can get an array of `PlayerMove` components (or even search for them itself using `FindObjectsOfType`), and your `CPUMove` method can be very simple:

```
// Expose the array to populate or validate in the Inspector.
public PlayerMove[] moves;

public void CPUMove() {
    // Generate a random move 0, 1, or 2
    // (Random.Range on ints never selects the last item)
    // and cast it to a MoveType to get Rock, Paper, or Scissors.
    var selectedMoveType = (PlayerMove.MoveType)Random.Range(0, 3);

    // Iterate over the move objects and toggle them on/off
    // based on whether they match the randomly-selected move type.
    foreach(var move in playerMoves)
        move.SetMoveSelected(move.moveType == selectedMoveType);
}
```